# Getting error while running query in SQL Server toad

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could any one please help me regarding that error getting in SQL Server Toad.Thanks in Advanced

```
select * from   
( 
SELECT  row_number() over ( order by (select null) ) rn, 
  Table1.column As RESPONSIBLE_ENTITY,
  ( with mycte as (
 SELECT  table2.objid, table2.title CONTRACT__TITLE
      FROM table2    
      WHERE
      (
      (table2.struct_type = 0) 

      )        
)
SELECT  Stuff(( SELECT ',' + cast(CONTRACT__TITLE as varchar(2000)) 
           FROM mycte t2
          WHERE t2.[objid] = t1.[objid]             
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,'')  AS [AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT]
  FROM mycte t1
GROUP BY t1.[objid]) AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT,
   table3.Coulmn1       BILL_LINE_ITEM__NET_AMOUNT,
   table3.Coulmn2      BILL_LINE_ITEM__BILL_TOTAL

 from table3 
          ) dt where rn between 0 and 100
```

error :-SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.

Comment: your cte needs to be at the start of the batch - you cant use them as a sub query

Comment: Could you please provide me some sample.

Comment: The whole query doesn't really make much sense - add some sample data and expected outcome. The reason you are getting the error you are is due to the nested CTE. can you use a subquery instead or rewrite it to use the CTE first

Comment: in AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT column i want data in comma separated values so i kept subquery in select query can you pls suggest in above query how we can run ?